# All of my files in home directory have 0620 file permission

Tags: macos, uti, permission

[image]

I don't the the exact reason why, but all the files in my home directory have 0620 file permission. What I remember is that I setup file sharing in System Preference.

[image]

Now, when I try to delete file in my home directory, this dialog box pops up to ask the password. I modified all the files back to permission 0774, but I still can't delete the file without answering the password.

What went wrong? How can I get the system back to normal?
I use Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2.

### ADDED

Refer to [this post also](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26776/what-is-the-mark-at-the-end-of-file-description)

Answer (score 1):

You must set the permissions of the folder the files are in as well.

Comment: Which means going up to the /Users folder and setting 0774 'apply to enclosed items'

Comment: 'apply to enclosed items' is dangerous, as it wipes out the existing permissions -- especially when the permissions you're applying are something weird like 774 (that's probably not what you want on *anything*, let alone everything).

Comment: @Lyken No, this is not the idea. Changing the permissions on folder itself (without recursing down) should be enough for the problem described.